# Make asynchronous function calls on in R

Tags: r

I have a function that that takes a while to run and it needs to be run multiple times but they can be run asynchronously. In the below example I have three input values to the function and at the moment they run in sequence.  How could they be run asynchronously?

```
vector <- c("1", "2", "3")
longRunningFunction <- function(x) {
  ## Do a bunch of things that takes some time
}
sapply(vector, longRunningFunction)
```

Comment: That package looks quite low level, I'd rather not have to know about the CPU cores and socket to make this work. May look further if nothing else appears. Ideally the library would take a bunch of things to do and handle all that for me.

Answer (score 3):

As @jenesaisquoi points out, it's pretty much as easy as:

```
require(parallel)
longRunningFunction <- function(x) {
  ## Do a bunch of things that takes some time
}
mclapply(vector, longRunningFunction, mc.cores = detectCores())
```